# How to sign and encrypt all sended mail via sendmail\postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail, encryption, x509

I have certificates x.509 for signing and enrypting outgoing emails. I want to create plain emails in some app (Ruby on Rails app in my case) and send it via sendmail with autosign and autocrypt solution.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a milter such as MIMEDefang: https://www.milter.org/milter/4

Comment: I tried to find documentation how to sign emails automatically, but failed. I'm new in this area. Do you have such tutorial?